# Merge dataframe rows by key column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large dataframe exported from a relational database. I would like to return unique rows based on a primary key column while combining observations from all other rows. I've attempted to do this using gather() but with no luck so far. Here is a simplified example of the original dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)
key <- c(rep(seq(1:3), 2))
x <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
y <- rep(c("foo", "bar"), 3)

df <- data_frame(key, x, y)


df

    key     x     y
   <int> <chr> <chr>
1     1     a   foo
2     2     b   bar
3     3     c   foo
4     1     d   bar
5     2     e   foo
6     3     f   bar
```

And the dataframe that I would like to return:

```
df

    key     x       y
   <int> <chr>   <chr>
1     1     a, d   foo, bar
2     2     b, e   bar, foo
3     3     c, f   foo, bar
```

I've tried

Comment: `df %>%
    group_by(key) %>%
    summarise(x = toString(x), y = toString(y))`? Or just `df %>%
    group_by(key) %>%
    summarise_all(toString)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`group_by` the `key` variable then `summarise` the other variables as `lists`. Calling `data.frame` as opposed to `data_frame` will return the data in the format you specify rather than as list columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  summarise(x = list(x), 
            y = list(y)) %>% 
  data.frame()

  key    x        y
   1    a, d    foo, bar
   2    b, e    bar, foo
   3    c, f    foo, bar
```

or

```
df %>% 
 group_by(key) %>% 
 summarise_all(list) %>% 
 data.frame()
```

does the same thing without specifying column names.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. I appreciate you demonstrating the summarise() and summarise_all() versions of the solution.

Comment: oh I need this in Python for a pandas dataframe